# Find more than a single repeating values in multiple columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I've tried my best to find an answer for this.

So I've a huge matrix, column A is ids. Columns B and C are certain values/scores.

Something like this:

```
A   B   C
876 0   1
159 2   3
887 0   1
876 1   2
597 1   3
159 2   3
```

Required:
I want matlab to automatically detect if the id is occurring again in column A. If yes, it should look for the values in columns B and C and see if they match up. If they do, the output should tell the id, the 2 values in columns B and C and the count (incidents).

Output for above example should be:

```
A   B   C   Count
159 2   3   2
```

Any help please?

Comment: Opps the matrix isn't clear. Mods can some one edit the example and the output to show a matrix please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative using `accumarray`: (I added data for testing).

```
clear
clc
close all

D = [876 0 1; 159 2 3; 887 0 1 ;876 1 2 ;597 1 3 ;159 2 3;876 0 1; 876 0 1];

%// Find unique rows and their indices
[x,~,z] = unique(D,'rows');

n=accumarray(z,1);

rowstokeep = find(n>1);

Out = [x(rowstokeep,:) n(rowstokeep,:)]

Out =

   159     2     3     2
   876     0     1     3
```

In order to sort the output according to the 4th column, use `sort` with the `descend` option like so:

```
[~,Idx] = sort(Out(:,4),'descend')
Out = Out(Idx,:)
```

Comment: No problem glad to help! `accumarray` is quite powerful haha!

Comment: Is there anyway to re-arrange the matrix Out to show the higher count first?? Please see my comment above

Comment: What's 1? It's sorting something else not the last column/count

Comment: Nice answer! I also thought of `accumarray` initially but then opted for `histc`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I've modified first row to provide a better example:

```
data = [ 876 1 2
         159 2 3
         887 0 1
         876 1 2
         597 1 3
         159 2 3 ];
[~, t, u] = unique(data, 'rows');
c = histc(u, 1:max(u));
ind = c>1;
result = [data(t(ind),:) c(ind)];
```

Result:

```
result =
   159     2     3     2
   876     1     2     2
```

Comment: Ok, one more question to make my life easier: How can I re-sort Result to show the higher count first. For example if the count for 159 is 3, it would list in the matrix higher than 876 which is 2? Thanks a lot!

Comment: To sort with higher count first: since count is 4th row, use `sortrows(result, -4)` (`-` means descending order)